# LNK1107 opengl32.dll in Visual Studio Express 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-express

I'm trying to compile some very simple code to make sure I don't have any unforeseen linker problems before I write several lines of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout << "Glfw initialization failed\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However I get the following error when I try to build: "LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2E8". My project is x64 so I assumed maybe I was linking the wrong dll with 32 bit architecture and checked its PE header in notepad. However it was "PE  d" d indicates it being x64 and L indicates it being x86. A tip I picked up from another question on SO.

I have tried linking multiple `opengl32.dll`'s in different directories: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll`, `C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll`, and `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-opengl_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_3c39618da01a51a8\opengl32.dll`

No success. I haven't been able to find any answers for my particular case, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should link to `.lib` files, not `.dll` files.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Where would I find `opengl32.lib` or an equivalent?

Comment: I don't know. I never used opengl.

Comment: @EdwardSnow Install Windows 10 SDK, then in your project properties, C++ Linker, Input, add "opengl32.lib" in lowercase letters to the text field.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you must link export .lib libraries, not .dll. Export libs usually produced when .dll is compiled, though .lib for OpenGL is an API library created independently from opengl32.dll which is part of video driver's package. You also need .lib from GLFW.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in my operating system where I could find this lib. Would you happen to know where I could find the one I need?

Comment: @Edward Snow it's in SDK. OpenGL32.Lib. What environment variables are set.